# Why is password hashing, e.g. php's password_hash so slow?

Tags: php, password-encryption, password-hash

I am using `password_hash` for password encryption. However there is a strange question, `password_hash` cost very long time. Here is a sample code.
this code will cost more than 1 second. Is that normal?

```
<?php
  $startTime = microtime(TRUE);
  $password='123456';
  $cost=13;
  $hash=password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['cost' => $cost]);
  password_verify($password,$hash);
  $endTime = microtime(TRUE);
  $time = $endTime - $startTime;
  echo $time;
?>
```

the result is :1.0858609676361

Comment: do you need too print password ? or you want to store it ?

Comment: @Fatemeh I'd imagine this is just debugging code.

Comment: @Burimi what ? Because what is good ?

Comment: @Fatemeh "Using salted md5 for passwords is a bad idea. Not because of MD5's cryptographic weaknesses, but because it's fast."

Comment: @Burimi aha, ok ...!

Comment: 13 is maximum cost for bcrypt, which translates to message 'hey function writer, do whatever you want but make this as strong as possible', so you are actually asking for long call yourself - it takes as much reasonable amount of hashing as possible. That doesn't mean it will be always hashing for one second - this depends on hardware - but using maximum cost is somewhat like "disregard the timing, just produce me best result you can" - and in password hashing best result is achieved by multiple rehashing.

Answer (score 13):

After running on [3v4l](http://3v4l.org/N0DtK) that seems perfectly normal.

Password hashing is not something you want optimize. In the words of [Leigh on the `hash` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php):

> If you are hashing passwords etc for security, speed is not your friend. You should use the slowest method.
>
> Slow to hash means slow to crack and will hopefully make generating things like rainbow tables more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 9):

The default algorithm for `password_hash`, `bcrypt`, is **designed** to be slow.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching

> In cryptography, key stretching refers to techniques used to make a possibly weak key, typically a password or passphrase, more secure against a brute force attack by increasing the time it takes to test each possible key. Passwords or passphrases created by humans are often short or predictable enough to allow password cracking. Key stretching makes such attacks more difficult.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table#Defense_against_rainbow_tables

> Another technique that helps prevent precomputation attacks is key stretching. When stretching is used, the salt, password, and a number of intermediate hash values are run through the underlying hash function multiple times to increase the computation time required to hash each password. For instance, MD5-Crypt uses a 1000 iteration loop that repeatedly feeds the salt, password, and current intermediate hash value back into the underlying MD5 hash function. The user's password hash is the concatenation of the salt value (which is not secret) and the final hash. The extra time is not noticeable to users because they have to wait only a fraction of a second each time they log in. On the other hand, stretching reduces the effectiveness of a brute-force attacks in proportion to the number of iterations because it reduces the number of computations an attacker can perform in a given time frame. This principle is applied in MD5-Crypt and in bcrypt. It also greatly increases the time needed to build a precomputed table, but in the absence of salt, this needs only be done once.

A full second is probably a little long - you could experiment with dropping `$cost` by one or two to bring it more to something like a tenth of a second, which will retain the effective protection while making the delay unnoticeable to your users.

Comment: A full second isn't that big of a deal for login. If users start to complain you can always drop the `$cost` but I would rather take a performance hit than have the algorithm complete sooner in this case.

Comment: @HuskyHuskie A GPU can do upwards of 10 billion MD5 hashes per second. A tenth of a second for a bcrypt hash is plenty of protection against rainbow tables.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you, but I don't think this is a black and white sort of thing. If the login is something like Facebook or Twitter where it will just remember me after I login once, then I don't think they will notice the 1 second. If the application needs to be more secure (government for example) then you may want it to also take longer. If the security isn't as big of a deal then yeah, lower the `$cost`. I just wanted to offer another perspective because there are valid reasons to have a high cost.

Comment: @HuskyHuskie A six character password has 19 billion combinations. That's 60 years to generate a rainbow table with bcrypt at 0.1 second/hash, and less than two seconds if it were a MD5 hash. I'm pretty comfortable with that level of security - if I'm building a banking site I'm probably requiring 8+ characters anyways, which brings me up to ~400 trillion possibilities to brute-force - something my PC can do in a day with MD5, but about a million years with bcrypt.

Comment: Again, I'm not disagreeing with you, but it's not a white and black situation. There is no reason that an attacker wouldn't just break up the rainbow generation into smaller pieces and generate it in parallel. As I said previously, a user probably isn't going to notice the difference between 0.1 seconds and 1 seconds if they are only logging in every once in a while. You just have to decide which is more important. At an academic level, a lower `$cost` does make the hash less secure than a higher `$cost`. It may not matter today, but it could matter tomorrow.

Comment: Tomorrow you up the cost factor. That's the beautiful thing about bcrypt!

Comment: Which works out great for inserting or updating those records, but you need the original password to send back through `password_hash` which requires the user to login or change their password. It's not as simple as changing the cost and it changes it across the board for the stored passwords.

Comment: 0.1 is fine. 1 second is likely too much as it does increase DOS risk.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's normal. That's what the `cost` parameter is for: it allows you to tweak the iteration count, making the hash slower or faster as needed.

You should always make the hash as slow as possible and as fast as necessary. The reason being that the only feasible attack on a password hash is brute force. You want to make the cost so large that it takes prohibitively long to simple brute force all possible values. That's your only real defence against attackers with password hashing to begin with.

One whole second seems prohibitively for your own use. You should lower that cost a bit to stay within a few hundred milliseconds at most. Adjust to your target systems as needed.

Answer (score 0):

To begin, `password_hash` is not encryption.

> password_hash() creates a new password hash using a strong one-way hashing algorithm. password_hash() is compatible with crypt(). Therefore, password hashes created by crypt() can be used with password_hash().

A hash is one-way, and whatever you pass into it will always have the same end-result, however there is no way for you get the original string from the hash. This is ideal for passwords because you want to store an obfuscated version of the user's password that you can easily compare at login without actually storing what the password is. This means if the database is compromised, so long as the passwords were hashed, the attacker wouldn't get the passwords, they would get the hashed passwords which are essentially useless (you can use rainbow tables and I'm sure other techniques to get the resulting hashes, but it takes a decent amount of effort).

This leads into your original question. Why are password hashes slow? They are slow because one of the only ways to get the original string from a hash is to re-generate that hash. So if it takes 1 second to generate each hash it becomes a bigger time sink than it would have been had you used a fast hash such as `md5` of a version of `sha`. Fast hashes are great for pretty much everything except for password storage.

Hopefully this answers your question. Just as an aside, I would strongly recommend generating a unique salt for each user and passing that in as one of the options into `password_hash`. This salt can be stored as plain-text in the database alongside the hashed password. Using a different salt for each password will add that into the password so a would-be attacker would have to generate a rainbow table for every salt that's in the database. At this point the attacker would likely utilize other techniques to get the passwords instead of a database breach.

Comment: Current best practice recommendation for `password_hash` is NOT to specify a salt but let `password_hash` generate that. Looks like that has probably changed in the last 5.5 years, so thought it worth noting for any future readers