# Laravel: Why database Seeder so slow on my fast pc

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, laravel-seeding

I'm running a typical Laravel version 5.2.23 on Homestead Vagrant box on Win10 with a fast NVMe ssd, Skylake i7 6700K cpu, 16GB ram. VirtualBox 5.0.26 r108824. I have 4GB and 2 CPU's allocated to the VM. Pretty much everything is default.

This very basic user table seeder takes 45 seconds for 1000 records and I had faster performance with a much slower pc before with Laravel 4.2. When I hit the localhost site it loads fast with data ( I simply echo the entire 1000 record user table in index.html ) so it doesn't seem like a network traffic slowdown between the VM and Win10, but idk.

Seeder is below.

```
class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder {

public function run() {
    DB::table('users')->truncate();

    for( $ii = 0; $ii < 1000; $ii++)
    DB::table('users')->insert([
        'name' => $ii,
        'email' => $ii.'@gmail.com',
        'password' => bcrypt('secret'),
    ]);


}

}
```

I know sometimes there can be weird Windows file system slowdowns with Linux based VM's, but I'm not sure whats going on here. Any help would be great.

Comment: Since the password is allways the same, you can crypt it once outside the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because bcrypt function call is slow. Usually it takes around 50ms for one operation(depending on machine it can be faster). 
(50ms * 1000op) / 1000ms = 50s.

See more [Why is php's password_hash so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30215781/why-is-phps-password-hash-so-slow)

Comment: Just tested it and spot on! Takes 4 seconds without the bcrypt! Duh I should know being a dev for this long I should have put system timers in there to see which part was slow.