# Laravel Hash works slow for create bulk user passwords

Tags: php, laravel

I'm importing users from a .csv file and I try to generate a password for each of them using:

```
Hash::make(Str::random(10))
// OR
bcrypt(Str::random(10))
```

The problem is that it takes about 8 sec for 150 users so **more than 6 min for all users**, there is a faster way to generate a password?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest hash for non-cryptographic uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665247/fastest-hash-for-non-cryptographic-uses)

Comment: Password hashes are supposed to be slow, it makes them that much harder to brute force.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30215781/why-is-password-hashing-e-g-phps-password-hash-so-slow (basically what Alex said in more detail)

Comment: How often are you bulk creating passwords that waiting 6 minutes is a problem? This shouldn't be a regular occurrence...

Comment: Huh, not the answer that I hoped for, but now I have a better understanding of why it takes that much time. Thank you!

Comment: Only 1 time per application, basically when a new client instance is created.

Comment: Just dispatch the password creation to a queued job.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443476/optimal-bcrypt-work-factor might be useful as well. You can adjust the work-factor in `Hash::make` ([see the manual](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/hashing#adjusting-the-bcrypt-work-factor)), just make sure you know what the actual effects are